# Preserve directory structure when unpacking attachments from PDF with pdftk?

Tags: pdf, attachment, directory-structure, pdftk

I am trying to pack and unpack attachments including a subdirectory hierarchy to a PDF with `pdftk ... attach_files` and `pdftk ... unpack_files`. However, while `attach_files` is capable of representing the subdirectory information by including the `/` separator in file names, `unpack_files` puts all files into one flat directory, silently overwriting files if the same name occurs multiple times. Is it possible to get preservation of the hierarchy when unpacking?

As workarounds I have used:

- Packing the attachments into a zip file and attaching the zip file. However, this way the attachment hierarchy is no longer easily accessible.
- Applying a bijective transformation on the path names, that maps the hierarchy to a flat structure and back. However, this way unpacking is possible *only* with a script doing the transformation.

Being directly able to preserve the hierarchy information already stored in the PDF would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not with the current version of pdftk, it is hardcoded to drop path information both when attaching and unpacking files. In fact, I would be surprised if any hierarchy information got stored in the PDF using pdftk.

That being said, it would not be too hard to write a patch to change this behaviour, I suggest opening an issue with a feature request.

Comment: Surprising as it may be, hierarchy information *is* currently stored by pdftk, though I suspect that it happens by storing a "string with slashes" as file name.

Comment: ... and it turns out I can't find any way to open issues other than the authors email address listed at https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: That project looks dead, but there is an active fork at https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/ (disclaimer: I am its maintainer)